# Fastlane error: `factory': [!] Can't find class 'adhoc' (RuntimeError)

Tags: ios, rubygems, provisioning-profile, fastlane

Check out the ticket for more information, just seeing if anyone on here would know.

Ticket: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

This error can happen when fastlane is installed using cask - "brew cask install fastlane" - instead of "brew install fastlane". I was following an outdated tutorial which lead to this error. Fastlane cask is now deprecated.